# How do I make an API call only run "onclick" instead of whenever the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I have this API call function here and I'm only limited to 10 calls per hour, but every time I load my page in browser it calls the functions. I only want it to run on the click of a button. Any Ideas?

```
const kaneki = {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '<api_key>',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'anime-quotes1.p.rapidapi.com'
}
};

fetch('blah', kaneki)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Make a button and add a click listener.

Comment: Now you've made your API key public I suggest you change it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @preston17 has indicated, you can create a button in the html file (or any element actually) and apply a click listener to it.

You could have something like this

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn-fetch"> Fetch Data </button>

   ....

  </body>
</html>
```

And  then you can create a reference to it in your JS file and add a listener

```
const fetchBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-fetch");
fetchBtn.addEventListener("click",  function(){
const kaneki = {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '6e3e7feab5mshcb53d970957352dp1303bejsnf471bf3638d9',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'anime-quotes1.p.rapidapi.com'
}
};

fetch('https://anime-quotes1.p.rapidapi.com/api/quotes/anime?title=tokyo%20ghoul', kaneki)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

That should do it. All the best in your learning journey :)